# IP address advice

Tags: ip, t1

Currently, we have a T1 line and Comcast.  The web traffic is mostly over Comcast while the email traffic is over the T1 line.  We want to swap it.  Is there an advantage to get multiple IP address through Comcast since the email and some web traffic will be over Comcast, or does it really not matter?  Since we only have one Comcast line coming into our building, will multiple IP address help reduce the bandwidth somehow?  Thanks, in advance, for your help.
- Charles

Comment: from the sounds of it I wouldn't touch the thing at all!

Comment: Sounds like you're getting rid of your T1... is that the case? (hard to tell from the way you asked the question)

Comment: well he did say swap, the reason I said don't touch a thing is because he doesn't know what he's doing!

Comment: @tony - you can't assume that he doesn't know what he's doing with the information given. There *may* be a good reason he wants to swap the two circuits.

Comment: Riiiight, he said 'swap' but then states that "the email and some web traffic will be over Comcast" (he could be referring to 'some traffic' as not having so much web traffic).  I'll read the question a few hundred times more, maybe eventually it will make sense.

Comment: yea but multiple ip's to increase bandwith!

Comment: @l0c0b0x I reread it a couple times now my mind hurtz.

Comment: is he going to bond his comcast connections :)

Comment: Folks, thanks for taking the time to read and respond to my inquiry; your kindness is greatly appreciated.  I didn't make the decision to swap; I was simply told to do it.

Comment: Folks, thanks for taking the time to read and respond to my inquiry; your kindness is greatly appreciated.  I didn't make the decision to swap; my supervisor told me to do it because Comcast has been spotty in our area and he didn't want those who use our website to have problems.  Thanks for confirming that multiple IP addresses won't reduce bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of IP addresses provisioned on a specific circuit has nothing to do with how much bandwidth is available.

I'm curious as to why you'd want to make this change. Unless your comcast connection is *very* slow (which I doubt), you're going to have much higher bandwidth available on that connection versus the T1. Unless your use case is much different than most places I've seen, web browsing will suck up a whole lot more bandwidth than email will.